# Copying charts Visual Studio (c++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, charts, copy, clipboard

What is the easiest way to copy `System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart^` to the clipboard?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it to a bitmap via a memory stream and then put that on the clipboard. Something like this:

```
MemoryStream^ pStream = gcnew MemoryStream();
yourchart->SaveImage(pStream, ChartImageFormat::Bmp);
Bitmap^ pBmp = gcnew Bitmap(pStream);
Clipboard::SetImage(pBmp);
```